# Opencv VideoCapture interruption callback

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add the fix referenced [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/6053) to fix the timeout issue with an IP camera.

As I understood, the fix was added with the new release of Opencv, but the ffmpeg binaries are not up to date. Thus the fix is ignored in the conditional compilation.

The project linked in the comments of the above link fixes everything, but it doesn't generate the dll needed to use with Opencv (or I don't know how to..)

I've tried to recompile Opencv with [this patch](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/compare/Itseez:master...alalek:ffmpeg_20160207?expand=1), and then copied newly generated opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll to my project. So far so good..

Now, my project uses 2 cameras: one is avc, the other is mjpg. With the old opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll file, both were working properly. With the new file, I get the warning "could not find codec parameters" and the mjpg camera never connects.

So my guess would be that something went wrong while building Opencv with CMake? But I received no error in the process.

I'm stuck here, and out of ideas on what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit. IDE is Visual Studio 2013 and OpenCV 3.10.